# How to get common library to read App.config of current executable

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, app-config

I have a common library and two executables.  Each executable refers to the common library for some functionality.  I would like the common library to read from the app.config of the exe which is currently running.

Is there specific API calls to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class:

```
var someValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someKey"];
```

would read the [appSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313(VS.71).aspx) section of the `app.config/web.config` of the currently executing process.

Comment: Hmmm... could've sworn I tried that already and it didn't work.  I was wrong.  Thanks!